# Ошибка совместимости 16-разрядной программы, с 32-разрядной системой при запуске OpenGL программы

Tags: c++, opengl

При запуске программы на OpenGL у меня вылезла ошибка о несовместимости 16-разрядной программы, с 32-битной системой.

> Версия этого файла несовместима с используемой версией Windows. С помощью сведений о системе определите необходимую версию программы (32- или 64-разрядную) и обратитесь к издателю программного обеспечения.

Вот сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gl/glut.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
glutCreateWindow("kek");
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
return 0;
}
```

И у меня вопрос, есть ли способ как нибудь переписать эту программу под 32-х битную систему?

Comment: "вылезла ошибка о несовместимости" - так ее надо было привести тут, а то непонятно, о чем идет речь

Comment: @VTT "Версия этого файла несовместима с используемой версией Windows. С помощью сведений о системе определите необходимую версию программы(32- или 64-разрядную) и обратитесь к издателю программного обеспечения."

Comment: Может у вас приложение 64 разрядное, а система 32 разрядная, не? В 2018 году надо постараться, чтобы собрать 16-битное приложение.

Comment: библиотеке на которой я написал это приложение уже больше 10 лет (OpenGL GLUT).

Comment: Может вы наконец объясните, почему не хотите заменить glut на freeglut? Я уже несколько раз спрашивал в комментах под другим вопросом, а ответа все нет.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я вам уже в чате отвечал по каким причинам я не хочу заменять GLUT на FREEGLUT

Comment: Пардон, перечитал чат еще раз. *"я пробовал его установить но когда я попытался запустить демку, которая выдаётся по дефолту в codeblocks, то она просто крашается"* Вы про это? Имхо, проще починить фриглут, чем заставить работать обычный.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну, так это ваше скромное мнение, что проще починить freeglut. Но ваше мнение применимо не ко всем. У меня проблема не с кодом, а с разрядностью файла

Comment: Специально скачал и проверил: freeglut 3.0.0 для mingw, [отсюда](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/). Демка, идущая в комплекте, скомпилировалась с первой попытки. Встроенный в codeblocks шаблон проекта для [free]glut брать не стал, взял пустой проект. Прописал в search directories пути до скачанных инклюдов и .a файлов. Прописал в linker settings `freeglut opengl32`. Закинул `freeglut.dll` в папку с экзешником. И все, все запустилось.

Comment: Маловероятно, но разница может быть в том, что у вас стоит обычный mingw (идущий в комплекте с codeblocks), а у меня - mingw-w64. Если так, попробуйте скачать mingw-w64 (в любом случая c codeblocks в комплекте идет какая-то древняя версия gcc, обновиться не помешает).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat насчёт mingw. Эта ошибка вылезла когда у меня стоял не mingw а MVS 2010.